# jquery ajax call fails ie7

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following function, which works in Firefox but not IE7:

```
function flagDocRead(currentdocid, currentuserid){

   alert(currentdocid);

   alert(currentuserid);

   $.get("./blocks/rc_importantdocs/flagdocread.php",{ docid: currentdocid, userid:    currentuserid });

}
```

currentdocid and currentuserid are both integers.

IE7 fails with "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

OK I fixed this by going to Tools->Internet Options->Advanced->[Security section]-> then Uncheck "Enable Native XMLHTTP support"